# Shrinkage methods: does non-convex constraints ($q < 1$) also induce sparsity?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, lasso, constrained-regression

I'm reading ESLII, in particular the chapter about shrinkage methods, lasso, and ridge regression.

The optimal model parameters for a given constraint $\sum | \beta_j |^q < \alpha $ are given by the equation

$$
\tilde{\beta} = \text{argmin}_\beta \left\{ \left(y_i - \beta_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p \beta_j x_{ij}\right)^2 + \lambda \sum_j^p |\beta_j|^q \right\}
$$

The argument they made to show that lasso ($q=1$) induces sparsity is the typical diamond vs ellipse picture.

[image: Lasso sparsity]

According to the book

> Unlike the disk, the diamond has corners; if the solution occurs at a corner, then it has one parameter $\beta_j$ equal to zero. When $p > 2$, the diamond becomes a rhomboid, and has many corners, flat edges and faces; there are many more opportunities for the estimated parameters to be zero.

However, the same argument can be applied when $0< q < 1$, since the solution has more chances to happen in one of the spikes of the contour plot, because if $q<1$ the countour plot is no longer convex.
[image: countour plots multiple q]
My question is then, would it be possible to perform feature selection and induce sparsity by constraining the parameters using $q < 1$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, however the unique thing about the lasso relative to other $L_p$ penalties is that it both induces sparsity and leads to a convex optimization problem. For $p > 1$ you have a convex optimization but no sparsity, while for $p < 1$ you have sparsity but no convexity. Convexity is important because it implies we can optimize the objective function efficiently; without convexity it is not easy to design a robust optimization procedure that runs quickly and is guaranteed to work.

Comment: OP see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing